# Injecting Corresponding implementation using StructureMap

Tags: c#, .net, ioc-container, structuremap

I have a class with the following structure

```
class Measure
{
    public MeasureType measureType { get; set; }
    public readonly IMeasureService _service ;

    public Measure(IMeasureService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
    public Calculate()
    {
        _service.Calculate(this);
    }
}
```

So i have different implementation of MeasureService for different measureTypes. Is it possible to use StructureMap to inject the corresponding MeasureService based on the measureType.

MeasureType is just an enum type and will never get changed throughout the instance.

Comment: `measureType` is a public mutable property. Is it expected that it could change multiple times during the lifetime of the object? Should this case be handled?

Comment: its not a public mutable property.it wont change after creation of measure instance.

Answer (score 2):

StructureMap cannot be instructed to do that for a simple reason:

- at the time the instance is created, the `measureType` property cannot be set.
- you cannot set the `IMeasureService` dependency at a later time, because it's `readonly` (and should probably be `private` as well)

Therefore, the solutions to this problem have more to do with the design of your classes than with StructureMap.

Here are the solutions I would typically choose in such a scenario:

---

#### 1) Delegate the task of choosing the right `IMeasureService` implementation to a different component.

The component could, for example, be called `MeasureServiceFactory` and have the following implementation:

```
public class MeasureServiceFactory
{
    private readonly Func<MeasureServiceType1> _type1Service;
    private readonly Func<MeasureServiceType2> _type2Service;

    public MeasureServiceFactory(
        Func<MeasureServiceType1> type1Service,
        Func<MeasureServiceType2> type2Service)
    {
        _type1Service = type1Service;
        _type2Service = type2Service;
    }

    public IMeasureService GetServiceForType(MeasureType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case MeasureType.Type1:
                return _type1Service();
            case MeasureType.Type2:
                return _type2Service();
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected measure type!");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that StructureMap will automatically inject the two `Func`s with appropriate calls to the container's `GetInstance()` method in order to properly resolve the required service.

Now, the `Measure` class will no longer have a direct `IMeasureService` dependency, but will depend on the factory instead:

```
public class Measure
{
    public MeasureType measureType { get; set; }
    private readonly MeasureServiceFactory _measureServiceFactory;

    public Measure(MeasureServiceFactory measureServiceFactory)
    {
        _measureServiceFactory = measureServiceFactory;
    }

    public void Calculate()
    {
        var service = _measureServiceFactory.GetServiceForType(measureType);
        service.Calculate(this);
    }
}
```

Note that no StructureMap configuration is required. The container will be able to resolve everything correctly.

---

#### 2) In order to keep the `Measure` class untouched, you could make the `MeasureServiceFactory` implement the `IMeasureService` interface:

```
public class MeasureServiceFactory : IMeasureService
{
    private readonly Func<MeasureServiceType1> _type1Service;
    private readonly Func<MeasureServiceType2> _type2Service;

    public MeasureServiceFactory(
        Func<MeasureServiceType1> type1Service,
        Func<MeasureServiceType2> type2Service)
    {
        _type1Service = type1Service;
        _type2Service = type2Service;
    }

    public void Calculate(Measure measure)
    {
        var service = GetServiceForType(measure.measureType);

        service.Calculate(measure);
    }

    private IMeasureService GetServiceForType(MeasureType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case MeasureType.Type1:
                return _type1Service();
            case MeasureType.Type2:
                return _type2Service();
            default:
                throw new ApplicationException("Unexpected measure type!");
        }
    }
}
```

Now, with your original `Measure` class, only this SM configuration is required to ake everything work:

```
x.For<IMeasureService>().Use<MeasureServiceFactory>();
```

---

#### 3) If the logic inside the `IMeasureService` implementors is not very complicated, consider putting it in a single class and perform different things depending on the `measureType` of the `Measure` object (which you already have access to).

I know, this seems like a step back, but there are some cases in which I prefer to do just that: when the business logic is not overly complex and pretty unlikely to change.

Comment: Good suggestions. infact scenario 1 is what i have in my code right now.I was just thinking if i could avoid the switch clause.

Comment: @AshleyJohn I think of a way to avoid the `switch`: using reflection + naming conventions. For example, for the enum member `Type1` we would search for a class named `MeasureServiceType1` and instantiate it using `Activator.CreateInstance`. This may be a good or bad approach; it mainly depends on the context.